# What were the recent heavy rains in Kyushu called?

Tags: words

What were the recent heavy rains in Japan called? Where the terms tsuyu or ooame used to describe the rain?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I frequently saw 大雨｛おおあめ｝ on the weather forecast while I was in Japan.  That describes what kind of rain is falling ([heavy rain](https://jisho.org/word/%E5%A4%A7%E9%9B%A8)).  If anything, this is what they used.

梅雨｛つゆ｝is a time of year, a rainy season (around mid May to mid July).  I would *not* use 梅雨 to describe the recent heavy rain because of its association with the season.

---

**Edit:**

I looked over some of my Japanese friends' social media posts, and I found that 大雨 was very commonly used.  Another word that was used was [豪雨｛ごうう｝](https://jisho.org/word/%E8%B1%AA%E9%9B%A8).  According to [Jisho.org](https://jisho.org/search/heavy%20rain), there is also 多雨｛たう｝, which makes sense if you know the kanji, but I haven't seen it used very much.

Below is a screen shot of a post from one of my friends that uses both 大雨 and 豪雨.

[image: Screen shot of post.]

Comment: 細かいことを言えば，このスクリーンショット上の「大雨」は「大雨特別警報」までで気象庁の出す特別の警報の名前です（「豪雨特別警報」はありません）．日常的に「大雨」を使うことが多いのは事実です．

Comment: @Yosh Thanks,  I actually did notice that (below they used #大雨) but I had already taken this screen shot, so I decided to be lazy.  I'll update that.

Answer (score 4):

Now it is formally named by the JMA: 「[平成30年７月豪雨](http://www.jma.go.jp/jma/press/1807/09b/20180709_meishou.html)」．See [Related article](https://www3.nhk.or.jp/news/html/20180709/k10011524701000.html) on NHK news.

Certain disasters are given names by the Japan meteorological agency and any formal documents discussing the issue will stick to it. [This article](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%B0%97%E8%B1%A1%E5%BA%81%E3%81%8C%E5%91%BD%E5%90%8D%E3%81%97%E3%81%9F%E8%87%AA%E7%84%B6%E7%8F%BE%E8%B1%A1%E3%81%AE%E4%B8%80%E8%A6%A7) on wikipedia lists such events.